# Why doesn't this local storage code work?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, local-storage

This is my code for index.html

```
<form action = "indo.html">
      <input type = "text" id = "tex">
      <button id = "tex">Submit</button>

    </form>
    <script>

      var o = document.getElementById("tex").value;
      localStorage.setItem("three", o);
    </script>
```

This is my code for indo.html

```
<script>
  var n = localStorage.getItem("three");
  document.write("Welcome "+n);
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually its working .But the value is empty .set Initial value on input .Because its set value on page load not after the form submit

**Try this**

```
<form action="indo.html">
  <input type="text" id="tex" value="something">
  <button id="tex">Submit</button>

</form>
<script>
  var o = document.getElementById("tex").value;
  localStorage.setItem("three", o);
</script>
```

**indo.html**

```
<script>
  var n = localStorage.getItem("three");
  document.write("Welcome " + n);
</script>
```

Comment: Can I change the value to the input value?

Comment: yes ofcourse.. do with https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_value.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you want save data into local-storage i suggest below code:

```
<form >
  <input type = "text" id = "tex">
  <button id = "texb">Submit</button>
</form>

function fun_sub(){
 const val = document.getElementById("tex").value;
  localStorage.setItem("three", val);
  console.log(localStorage.getItem("three"));
  window.open("/indo.html", "_self");
}
```

In your code, name id of input element and button element is same! this mistake return error if you call getElementById in javascript ,and you must consider that when you write a code and you want call code again after render page, you should call it in a function.